# It is impossible to delete a user from firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an application in which I want add a function to remove a user from Firebase. I follow the official documentation but I can not do it. I get a warning in the console

> Error This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)deleteUser {
   FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
   [user deleteWithCompletion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
      if (error) {
          NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
      } else {
          NSLog(@"Delete user");
      }
   }];
```

}

Perhaps somebody faced a similar problem, tell me how to solve?"

Comment: I left a comment explaining the reason for this message when you posted [this exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790469/error-when-deleting-a-user-from-the-database-firebase) a few weeks ago. If a comment isn't clear, just ask for more help then and there. Re-posting the same question weeks later is not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Firebase api's doc in website, you can see your code to delete user in firebase must logined recently.

if you logined for a while. you must re authentication.

here is how to re auth :

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
FIRAuthCredential *credential;

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

[user reauthenticateWithCredential:credential completion:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
  if (error) {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}];
```

in security sensitive operation such as(delete user, set password, set-email...), you must re auth first.